# Deploying an AWS CDK stack, ENOENT error but file exists

Tags: aws-cdk

I can successfully build a cdk stack. When deploying, I get the following output (I changed the name of the stack to my-project):

my-project:  start: Building bbc607a4ac6f868ba9e45e9f9ba5f1c3cf4e3b14d0e690f4c9ce3bb9cb9f964b:910458460161-eu-central-1
my-project:  success: Built bbc607a4ac6f868ba9e45e9f9ba5f1c3cf4e3b14d0e690f4c9ce3bb9cb9f964b:910458460161-eu-central-1
my-project:  start: Building 87982448b5f41e7ee4a7bb49f3bc091290bac6433b3a7155eb9c6b02619deec4:910458460161-eu-central-1
my-project:  success: Built 87982448b5f41e7ee4a7bb49f3bc091290bac6433b3a7155eb9c6b02619deec4:910458460161-eu-central-1
my-project:  start: Publishing bbc607a4ac6f868ba9e45e9f9ba5f1c3cf4e3b14d0e690f4c9ce3bb9cb9f964b:910458460161-eu-central-1
my-project:  start: Building 3c4cd26fe8b60b35c17579621245911d275a5676f6ae704257c6652d2f825998:910458460161-eu-central-1
my-project:  success: Built 3c4cd26fe8b60b35c17579621245911d275a5676f6ae704257c6652d2f825998:910458460161-eu-central-1
my-project:  start: Publishing 87982448b5f41e7ee4a7bb49f3bc091290bac6433b3a7155eb9c6b02619deec4:910458460161-eu-central-1
my-project:  start: Building 6ec7496703495c2ec88efaf08a099bd34ff79241da190bade4794a89b3364c23:910458460161-eu-central-1
my-project:  success: Built 6ec7496703495c2ec88efaf08a099bd34ff79241da190bade4794a89b3364c23:910458460161-eu-central-1
my-project:  start: Publishing 3c4cd26fe8b60b35c17579621245911d275a5676f6ae704257c6652d2f825998:910458460161-eu-central-1
my-project:  start: Publishing 6ec7496703495c2ec88efaf08a099bd34ff79241da190bade4794a89b3364c23:910458460161-eu-central-1
node:internal/process/promises:288
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/.../my-project/cdk.out/asset.87982448b5f41e7ee4a7bb49f3bc091290bac6433b3a7155eb9c6b02619deec4/nodejs/node_modules/.bin/adler32'] {
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'stat',
path: '/home/.../my-project/cdk.out/asset.87982448b5f41e7ee4a7bb49f3bc091290bac6433b3a7155eb9c6b02619deec4/nodejs/node_modules/.bin/adler32'
}

Node.js v18.17.0
It looks like something is missing in the generated files. However, the file exists when I check for it!

I tried the following: upgrading aws-cdk, manually installing adler32 to that directory, deleting the stack and redeploying. None worked.

Maybe useful infos:

- I installed in a layer a local module and xml2js;
- `ls` finds the file, and the permissions are `lrwxrwxrwx` so it's a link; I get `cat: adler32: No such file or directory` if I try to `cat` it.

Can anyone help me solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Very stupidly, the link was there but the linked file not: it was enough to check for the link path.
I solved the issue deleting the node modules directory and package-lock file, then reinstalling according to the `package.json`.